# How to run MSI installer action on upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, upgrade

We're running custom installer logic in a C# class via the System.ComponentModel.RunInstallerAttribute annotation. We use the VS2010 MSI installer.

Problem: this logic is not executed when we do an upgrade. Is there a way to execute code for upgrade installs?

Answer (score 0):

What condition are you using for the custom action? If you are using "Not Installed" is should run.

Also, just to sure I understand the problem correctly. When you do an upgrade the custom action is in the new package, i.e. the one upgrading, not the one being removed?